# Sci Fi movie murder/space

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to remember the name of a movie I saw on Syfy I think earlier this year.

It was an 80s movie I think. A crew on a cargo ship. Something happens and the captain panics and steals away on the lifeboat, leaving the crew.
They realise there's not enough air for everyone and start to kill each other. One of the characters has a dog I think a Westie who gets killed. Meanwhile the captain is running a PR scam but is scuppered when the rescue ships find two survivors. One guy put the other into a medical stasis pod to slow his breathing so they both could live.

What's it called?!!!

Comment: And here I was going to suggest *Lifepod* itself...

Comment: Trapped in Space!! Of course!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the 1995 made-for-TV movie [Trapped in Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108380/).

> After an accident during a routine trip to Venus, a spaceship has only
>   enough oxygen left for three people... out of five on board.