A film where the police investigate the death of a passenger on a trip into space? 4 people on board, incl. the owner of the company + a Black pilot
I'm looking to identify this film where a private company will sell trips into space—the ship returns with one dead body. There were four people on board, including the owner of the company and a Black pilot. The three remaining people on board are suspiciously evasive.
Two investigators discover the dead man had been shot on the ship, out of fear that there was not enough oxygen for all four. He was then pushed out into space before being brought back in.
I watched this film on August 10, 2024, at approximately 1 AM on the French TV station "TF1 Films." I did not see the beginning credits. At the end, I believe it said that the French title was Alter Ego and gave the director's last name as Garcia. It did not say what the original American title was.
By the way, Alter Ego doesn't seem like a very appropriate title for this storyline.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Very likely a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102995/sci-fi-movie-murder-space

This description did remind me of Trapped in Space, but only in terms of having a vaguely similar premise. The specific plot points mentioned here don't line up with that film.

I watched this film August 10 at apx 1 AM on the French TV station "TF1 films".  I did not see the beginning credits.  At the end, I believe it said that the French title was "Alter Ego" and gave the director's last name as Garcia. It did not say what the original American title was.  BTW, "Alter Ego: does not seem like a very appropriate title for this story-line,

Did it look like a newer film or an older one? And are there any similar films you can rule out? Trapped in Space (1994), for example?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

I've seen something like that recently (not necessarily made recently), but it was a TV series which had an episode like that (not a movie). Most likely a police-procedural type, as that's been my staple of late. Possibly one of the CSI franchise, possibly "Lucifer", or "Castle".  If I recall correctly, the zero-g recoil of firing a gun caused a bruise on the back of the gunman, leading to the truth coming out.
